# Linq Include Select from Navigation Property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using the following in an attempt to locate a single member record associated with a specific organisation;

```
var dataRow = db.Organisation
    .Include(x => x.Member.Select(m => m.Guid == MemberGuid))
    .Where(x => x.Guid == OrganisationGuid)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

However this throws the following error;

"The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path"

The Include path is valid and if I take out ".Select(m => m.Guid == model.MemberGuid)" it returns a collection of members for the organisation which I then have to process to locate the required member.

Is there a way to locate the specific member without returning the whole collection?

Comment: I think you might want to structure your query differently, and avoid using Include in this case, if you give a little more information about what data you want out of each collection, I can help you with this.

Comment: The Organisation and Member tables have a many-to-many relationship using the OrganisationMember table which of course is not displayed in EF6 as it is a navigation property.
So I am trying to determine if an Organisation has a specific Member - I don't want to return the entire member collection from the Include.

Answer (score 4):

There are two mistakes in your query. First, you are trying to use `.Select` to filter the records, you will only get `true/false` records in the column. You should use `.Where` instead. Second, `.Include` accepts a navigation property, not the query.

```
var dataRow = db.Organisation
    .Include(x => x.Member)
    .Where(x => x.Member.Guid == MemberGuid && x.Guid == OrganisationGuid)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

An alternative solution is using join:

```
var dataRow = (from o in db.Organisation
              join m in db.Member
              on o.MemberGuid equals m.MemberGuid
              where o.Guid == OrganisationGuid && m.Guid == MemberGuid
              select o).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the tables use an intermediate table to create a many-to-many relationship.  Does this make any difference to to the 1st example as I get the error "'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<_projectname_.Data.Member>' does not contain a definition for 'Guid' and no extension method 'Guid' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<_projectname_.Data.Member>' could be found" when trying to use "`x.Member.**Guid** == MemberGuid`"